# Display error when using top with the memory bar or block graph

Tags: command-line, 17.10

Most of the time when using top in the display mode with a memory bar or block graph (by pressing "m" in top), the graph exceeds the scale by far and also the displayed number for memory usage is not correct. In the usual "numbers only" view the numbers are correct.
I was not able to figure out when this problem appears or not, but it appears most of the times for me.
I attached a screenshot to illustrate the problem.

Does anyone know why this can happen?
I am using Ubuntu 17.10.

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if it is locale-related? does the behavior differ if you invoke `top` as `LC_ALL=C top` ?

Comment: No, looks exactly the same...